# Calculate user availability base on schedule table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have got a table structure as below:

```
create table schedule_tab
(
    schedule_id serial
            primary key,
    user_id     integer     not null,
    type        varchar(64) not null,
    start_date       timestamp   not null,
    end_date       timestamp not null
);

insert into schedule_tab (user_id, type, start_date, end_date) values
   (1, 'AVAIL', '2023-01-04 06:00:00', '2023-01-04 22:00:00'),
   (1, 'AVAIL', '2023-01-05 06:00:00', '2023-01-05 22:00:00'),
   (1, 'AVAIL', '2023-01-06 06:00:00', '2023-01-06 22:00:00'),
   (1, 'BUSY',  '2023-01-04 08:00:00', '2023-01-04 12:00:00'),
   (1, 'BUSY',  '2023-01-05 17:00:00', '2023-01-05 23:00:00');
```

[db example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3sZytM5gtKNMBc2UQwYBAV/0)

It is possible to prepare an SQL query (PostgreSQL 12.6) that returns a user's real slots when a specific user is available.
Records with type `AVAIL` represent user availability. On the other hand `BUSY` shows when the user has got reserved already time.

For example for date: 2023-01-04 should be returned 2 slots between 6:00-8:00 and 12:00-22:00 because between 8:00-12:00 my user is busy.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded to PostgreSQL v14, that would be simple using multiranges:

```
SELECT range_agg(tsrange(start_date, end_date)) FILTER (WHERE type = 'AVAIL')
     - range_agg(tsrange(start_date, end_date)) FILTER (WHERE type = 'BUSY')
FROM schedule_tab;
```

If you want the multirange split up:

```
SELECT lower(q2.range) AS available_from,
       upper(q2.range) AS available_to
FROM (SELECT range_agg(tsrange(start_date, end_date)) FILTER (WHERE type = 'AVAIL')
           - range_agg(tsrange(start_date, end_date)) FILTER (WHERE type = 'BUSY') AS ranges
      FROM schedule_tab) AS q1
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(q1.ranges) AS q2(range);

   available_from    │    available_to     
═════════════════════╪═════════════════════
 2023-01-04 06:00:00 │ 2023-01-04 08:00:00
 2023-01-04 12:00:00 │ 2023-01-04 22:00:00
 2023-01-05 06:00:00 │ 2023-01-05 17:00:00
 2023-01-06 06:00:00 │ 2023-01-06 22:00:00
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Unfortunately we have got PG 12.6